# PHP How get at values for a list of buttons

Tags: php, list, button, postback

I want a list of buttons in a form and on postback I'd like to interrogate the list to see what status the buttons are at (by background colour if you are interested.)

The following codes says that Buttonx is undefined

However using the text boxes it works fine.

In javascript I can get at the array of buttons - at least in my real program.

If this is not possible, and an explanation would be useful, does anyone have a workaround at how I can get at the buttons in my postback. (In the real code the buttons are dynamically created depending on an sql query list)

```
<?php      
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      var_dump($_POST['Buttonx']);
  }
?>

<form name="RegisterStudents" action="" method="post">
  <button  type="submit" name="myButton">Submit</button>
  <!--
  <input type="text" name="Buttonx[]" id="B0" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="Buttonx[]" id="B1" value="1" />
  <input type="text" name="Buttonx[]" id="B2" value="2" />
  <input type="text" name="Buttonx[]" id="B3" value="3" />
  --> 

  <button type="button" name="Buttonx[]" id="B0" >0</button>
  <button type="button" name="Buttonx[]" id="B1" >1</button>
  <button type="button" name="Buttonx[]" id="B2" >2</button>
  <button type="button" name="Buttonx[]" id="B3" >3</button>

</form>
```

Thanks
Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Using forms you cannot pass the form elements with `type="button"` to server their values are not passed to server instead you have to use any other type to send the information to server
on client side you can access their values this is the default nature of html

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot pass the **type="button"** to the server, instead use checkboxes?
2. You have the **id="B0"** or so but instead it should be **value="B0"** and not **"id"**

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` is not really mature in browsers yet. Look at this link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag%5Fbutton.asp

```
If you use the <button> element in an HTML form, different browsers may 
submit different values. Use <input> to create buttons in an HTML form.
```